# Remove unwanted hosts being pinged by Mongo mms agent

Tags: mongodb-mms

Does anyone know how to stop Mongo MMS agent to stop pinging unwanted hosts that aren't accessible. My MMS agent is trying to monitor certain hosts that are not supposed to be reachable anyway and then continuously logs the following errors in the log:

ERROR Problem collecting blocking data from: host-xx:51017 - exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
ConnectionFailure: could not connect to host-xx:51017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Although the agent is correctly monitoring the hosts needed for this configuration, it thinks the host-xx is also a part of the same set and makes a failed attempt to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually remove host from being monitored. To do this go to the `Hosts` section.
[image]
Click on the recycle bin icon on the very right of the host row in the host table. Keep in mind that if you have deleted the host and want it back you need to add it from the very beginning (you can not restore it).

Comment: Hi Salvador Thanks for responing. But the hosts that I want to remove do not appear in the MMS API.The hosts for which errors are being recorded only appear in the Monitoring Agent Log because obviously the agent is unable to connect to them. I think it has something to do with the python (.py) scripts where my agent is running rather than modifying in API because it is the agent that is sending that info and it is also sending unwanted 3 hosts info that the agent for this particular group is not supposed to monitor.

Comment: have you previously removed them how in the way I described it?

Comment: No the MMS for this group was just recently configured. Rest all other hosts for this group are discovered and monitored by this agent on its own. I've six different groups of hosts under my MMS user and the 3 unwanted hosts mentioned here belong to a different group and they are already been monitored by another agent. Not sure why this agent is even trying to ping those. I think I'll take this question to 10gen MongoDB folks.